# How to switch macbook between 2 video configurations

Tags: macos, video

I routinely have to transport my Macbook (Monterrey OS) between 2 offices in my house

1. one has a Docking station that connects 2 monitors to the laptop via a single USB-C connection
2. the other has no docking station but has 3 monitors connected via USB-C adaptors.

I always keep my laptop lid closed in both scenarios so that the internal display is off

The problem is that it takes a lot of time for the laptop to reconfigure itself and sometimes displays don't work unless powered off & on repeatedly, it takes several minutes of waiting for it to reconfigure and occasionally the laptop even crashes and reboots.

So my question is: what is the recommended procedure for switching configurations;  should I lock the computer before detaching from each configuration?

Any tips to make the transition more graceful are welcome

Comment: I'd try shutting it down, so it only discovers it's changed at boot.

Comment: I have to switch between my 2 offices in my home several times a day and having to shut down and start over each time I do that is certainly not something I want to have to do

Comment: The trouble with trying to hotplug is that *everything* in the chain has to be capable. That's rare. Try it & see.